# Error deploying a grails application on jboss 5.1.2 with Oracle 11g as backend.

Tags: grails

Below is my datasource.groovy and followed by errors I get. Any insight/guidance will be appreciated.

```
dataSource {
pooled = true
driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
}
```

```
hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache = true
cache.use_query_cache = false
cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
development {
dataSource {
dbCreate = "update"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@fcoh1s-z-arlu48.fas.gsa.gov:2500:gtran11g"
username = "username"
password = "password"

}

}
}
```

**ERRORS**

```
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/GWACPriceTool-0.1]] (main) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:h2:mem:grailsDB;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:126)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:153)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:170)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:121)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4389)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:321)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:122)
at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256)
at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like somehow the DB URL is not getting picked up correctly. Check for a typo or something in your config.

`Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:h2:mem:grailsDB;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000'`

Answer (score 0):

What is the command you are using to create the war file you are deploying?

If using "grails war" then this will default to the production environment. See http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Command%20Line/war.html.

Currently you don't have any settings for the production database, to use your development database for the deployed war use the "grails dev war" command to create it.

The other option instead of using "grails dev war" is to set -Dgrails.env=development as a start up parameter. See http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html/start-stop.html. This allows you to deploy the same war to all environments.